# Gurobi Python: Does the code satisfy the constraint?.

Tags: python, gurobi, mixed-integer-programming

I am trying to write the constraints as shown in the image, But can't able to achieve the desired result.

[image]

> The result will be if the task uses the electricity then `x` binary
>   variable will be 1 it imposes `delta` binary variable to 1 in another
>   constraint. So the task has to use the electricity until the end of
>   the task runtime.
>
> Here k is the time at which task started o_{i,j} is the total run time
>   of the task.

I have tried this:

```
    m.addConstrs((x[t, u, app, task]<= x[time_slots[t_index + each_task_time], u, app, task]+ 1 - delta[t, u , app, task]  
for t_index, t in enumerate(time_slots) 
for u in users for app in appliances 
for task in task_appliances[app] 
for each_task_time in range(int(task_time[app][task])+1)
if t_index < (len(time_slots)- task_time[app][task])), 
name = "task_end_electricity1")
```

Where `task_time[app, task]` is the run time of task j of appliance i.

**Binary variables**

```
x[t, u, app, task] : indicates whether task j of appliance i of user u at time slot k processed by electricity or not; 1 = processed, 0 = not processed

delta[t, u , app, task] : that takes value 1, if the task j of appliances i of user u starts running at time t. Or O if it doesn't start.
```

**Example data:**

```
time_slots = ['k1', 'k2','k3', 'k4', 'k5']
users = ['u1', 'u2', 'u3', 'u4', 'u5']
appliances = ['washingmachine', 'dryer', 'dishwasher']
task_appliances = {'washingmachine':['movement', 'heating','washing'],
                   'dryer': ['drying1', 'drying2'], 
                   'dishwasher': ['movement', 'heating1', 'wash']}

task_time = {'washingmachine':{'movement': 1 , 'heating': 1, 'washing': 1}, 
             'dryer':{'drying1': 1, 'drying2': 1}, 
             'dishwasher': {'movement': 1, 'heating1': 1,'wash': 1}}
```

Can somebody correct me?.

Comment: What's your result? And could you please provide example data for `time_slots, appliances, task_appliances, task_time`? Otherwise it's very hard to help you.

Comment: @JohnnyDrama I have added requirements you mentioned please check it.

Comment: At the moment, you seem to enforce that once a task starts at time `k`, it has to be active on time `k  + o_{ij}`. Should you not enforce is has to be active every single time epoch between `k` and `k + o_{ij}`?

Comment: @loannis I have changed the code now. Can you tell me is that correct.

Comment: It is hard to judge what is going on having only this part. Did you try to run it? Does the solution you take make sense? In general, you may want to rethink (i) the design of your data structures (e.g., is it necessary to have nested dictionaries?) and (ii) the way you add constraints. For a small problem, looping over the ranges and adding one constraint at a time will not make any difference in performance, and the code will be much easier to understand.